# HTML & CSS Section ID Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following html code works with the concurrent CSS file but the "sections" do not look right and the copyright doesn't show up in a white section.  I'm subscribed to PLuralsight because I have to wait for academic funding but I've learned how to do the homework through youtube and other venues like codepen (love this program btw and Notepad ++).

The "main" Section ID should be in borders and centered and the "secondary" Section ID should look like it doesn't have borders and the white should go all the way up to the edge of the header and past the footer, where the copyright should show in the white part of the whole.  Basically, I'm confused as to what they are requiring for it to look the way they want it.  IDs take precedence over classes and if you have two sections how do you make one section take over the whole thing while the second one just looks like a box?

```css
/* site2.css */

header,
footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: solid 1px black;
  /*font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;*/
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

body {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

a {
  color: green;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bordered-image {
  border: solid 1px #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#main {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #202020;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#secondary {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #FF0000;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: align-top;
}

#results {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.simple-form {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*  position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    */
}

.simple-form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.simple-form input[type=text],
.simple-form select,
.simple-form input[type=password],
.simple-form textarea {
  width: 150px;
}

.simple-form input[type=submit] {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 989px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

h3 {
  color: #0066ff;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!--index2.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site2.css">
  <title>Github Hub</title>
</head>

<body>
  <class="container">
    <header>
      <div>
        <img src="img/logo.gif" class="bordered-image" />
      </div>
      <div>This is a site to search Github for interesting projects.</div>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
      <p>In this
        <em>sample site</em>, we'll show a list of <a href="http://github.com">Github</a> projects
        <span>and the data</span> about
        <strong>those projects</strong>.
      </p>
      <form action="http://wilder.azurewebsites.net/echo" method="POST" class="bordered-image simple-form" id="gitHubSearchForm">
        <label for="searchPhrase">Search Phrase:</label>
        <input type="text" name="searchPhrase" id="searchPhrase" />
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="useStars" id="useStars" checked="true" />
        <label for="useStars">Use Stars?</label>
        <br/>
        <label for="langChoice">Language:</label>
        <select name="langChoice" id="langChoice">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>JavaScript</option>
    <option selected>C#</option>
    <option>JavaScript</option>
    <option>Ruby</option>
    </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
      </form>
      <div id="results" class="bordered-image">
        <div id="resultList">This is where results will live...eventually.
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="secondary">
      <div>
        <h3>Additional Resources</h3>
        <p>Visit the
          <span class="highlight">Resources</span> section of our website for additional help.
        </p>
        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
        <p>Please contact the
          <span class="highlight">author</span> for additional resources at shawn@github.com.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section <footer>
    &copy; 2014 Shawn Wildermuth LLC
    </footer>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You say you love Notepad++? You won't say after seeing [Perfect Workflow in Sublime Text (Tuts+)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AV9zJH2n_Y&list=PLfOUVua2ZO5hyp62n0BnGVLrcP-djHA7E).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second section tag wasn't closed.

Also :

1 : you forgot the 'div' in your div tag with the container class.

2 : the div 'resultList' (inside the div 'results'), is not closed.

You can also put the script tags in the head and wrap you javascript code inside a function to be sure that the code will be executed after the window is loaded, like that :

```
window.onload = function(){
  //your index.js code
}
```

You have to avoid multiple carriage return and *br* tag because you also create additional nodes in the DOM.
Instead of this :

```
<p>Visit the
 <span class="highlight">Resources</span> section of our website for additional help.
</p>
```

you can do this :

```
<p>Visit the <span class="highlight">Resources</span> section of our website for additional help.</p>
```

As said above, a text editor like sublime text will help you to make it more readable for you.
You should adopt a better indentation to make you code more clean and more readable for you or others if you have to share it. It make it more easer to debug and it's more maintainable.

Instead of the *br* tag, you can try to think about a more simple structure for your design and your code, before coding. In the collection a *book apart*, you have the book *CSS3 for web designers* by *Dan Cederholm* that can be a good help for making you design and your code better.

Comment: Thank you for your critique...I'm awaiting funds for Pluralsight for class.  I've fixed most of those errors and am working on the indentation.  It's been awhile since I've programmed especially on a website.  I'm used to VB but have been dying to learn this CSS!  I'm basically working from scratch without a book, and limited funds, to take this class.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. From scratch? I see. Here are some links to web development courses : 
[The net ninja](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW5YeuERMmlnqo4oq8vwUpg/playlists) and [kirupa](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/learn_html_css.htm)

I'm sure that if you follow the steps of those courses, you will see some progress after two weeks. Enjoy.

Comment: I'm taking on thank you...I've not gotten the materials yet and my voucher expired.  Monday...yes I get them Monday!

Answer (score 1):

You did not close the section tag on line # 172. (line # 56 in the HTML)

Check it now: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEVMqL

```
<style>
header, footer {
background-color: lightgray;
border: solid 1px black;
/*font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;*/
}

footer {
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

body {
font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: darkgreen;
}

a {
color: green;
}

html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.bordered-image {
border: solid 1px #444;
border-radius: 2px;
}

#main {
border: solid 1px #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: white;
color: #202020;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
}

#secondary {
border: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: white;
color: #FF0000;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: align-top;
}

#results {
padding: 2px;
width: 600px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.simple-form {
padding: 2px;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
/*  position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
right: 5px;
*/
}

.simple-form label {
font-weight: bold;
}

.simple-form input[type=text],
.simple-form select,
.simple-form input[type=password],
.simple-form textarea {
width: 150px;
}

.simple-form input[type=submit] {
background-color: green;
color: white;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 3px;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.container {
width: 989px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;
}

h3 {
color: #0066ff;
letter-spacing: 7px;
}

.highlight{
background-color: yellow;
font-weight: bold;
}

header nav {
float: right;
margin-right: 5px;
}

header nav li {
display: inline;
font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site2.css">
<title>Github Hub</title>  
</head>

<body>
<class="container">
<header>
<div>
<img src="img/logo.gif" class="bordered-image" />
</div>
<div>This is a site to search Github for interesting projects.</div>
</header>
<section id="main">
<p>In this
<em>sample site</em>, we'll show a list of <a 
href="http://github.com">Github</a> projects
<span>and the data</span> about
<strong>those projects</strong>.
</p>
<form action="http://wilder.azurewebsites.net/echo" method="POST" 
class="bordered-image simple-form" id="gitHubSearchForm">
<label for="searchPhrase">Search Phrase:</label>
<input type="text" name="searchPhrase" id="searchPhrase" />
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="useStars" id="useStars" checked="true" />
<label for="useStars">Use Stars?</label>
<br/>
<label for="langChoice">Language:</label>
<select name="langChoice" id="langChoice">
<option>All</option>
<option>JavaScript</option>
<option selected>C#</option>
<option>JavaScript</option>
<option>Ruby</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
<div id="results" class="bordered-image">       
<div id="resultList">This is where results will live...eventually.
</div>
</section>
<section id="secondary">
<div> <h3>Additional Resources</h3>
<p>Visit the 
<span class="highlight">Resources</span> section of our website for 
additional help.
</p>
<h3>Contact Information</h3>
<p>Please contact the 
<span class="highlight">author</span> for additional resources at 
shawn@github.com.
</p>
</div>
</section>
<footer>
&copy; 2014 Shawn Wildermuth LLC
</footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (: Can you approve the answer?

Comment: I still have the two sections showing up in white and the copyright not showing in the white?! I've done the homework already just need to adjust these settings.  Apparently, this should not have happened or I have a section that should be a child section.

Comment: Simply add the background color to the footer. (line 10 in the css) Codepen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEVMqL

Comment: How do I show you a screenshot of what it should look like?

Comment: Between the 2nd section and the copyright there is some margin in green.That's your issue? If yes, see now: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEVMqL

Comment: How did you change that and how do I take out the margin of green above section main and section secondary?

Comment: See updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEVMqL With the copyright issue, you closed the section before starting the footer. With the margin between the two sections, you had a "margin" variable that was not specific. I changed the margin variable to be specific to where you want the margin.

Comment: Ok...I see where I went wrong there, easy code can't believe I missed it but the Header is the same problem should I close it right before the "main" section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149741/discussion-between-janine-mcdaniel-and-david-somekh).

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with both your markup (HTML) and your stylesheet (CSS). It's difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish given your imprecise verbiage as well as the HTML/CSS itself, but I'll make some recommendations.

First, whenever you write some HTML, run it through this validator provided by the W3C, it will point out specific errors in your markup.

[W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) 

Here is just a sample of the errors I got while running your markup through it
[image]

Second, I recommend doing some reading and maybe some tutorials about semantics in HTML, there are many errors in your usage of tags, you can start here

[MDN HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5)

In your code you have invalid tags, `<class="container">` is not valid HTML. You're missing a closing angle bracket on your `</section`. Browsers are extremely permissible when it comes to writing poor markup and css, this is both a good thing (it will do its best to fill in and fix what it thinks you are meaning to accomplish) and a bad thing because you can write incorrect HTML and not realize it. Like I said before, I'm not really quite sure what you are trying to accomplish but I'll take a stab at pointing you in the right direction.

1. Yes, you are correct to say that an 'ID' selector will take precedence of over a class attribute due to specificity, but there is much more to understanding how *cascading* stylesheets work, including the order that the rule is implemented within the stylesheet itself (rules implemented at the bottom of the page can override rules set earlier in the document). Try working your way down from your outermost element (topmost) down into the nesting of the tree.
2. If I am gleaning what you are trying to say about your 'main' div and your 'secondary' div, you want to place the secondary div and the footer *inside* the main div to accomplish your goal.